# Hide nav-button depending on the current state change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i hide/show this button based on my current view?

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button id="search_button" class="button button-icon  ion-ios-search button-clear"  ng-click="search()">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: Do you mean route by view? Is this directive a custom one? Which router do you use? ui-router or angularJS routeProvider?

Comment: The navigation to the different views happens from an Ionic Side menu. Also i use the angular routeProvider

Comment: Great, then the `$stateChangeSuccess` event is what you are looking for. (or `$viewContentLoaded ` basicly the same...). If you have a parent container, my solution will suit you. If you don't I recommend you to add a controller in the html in the body tag. And handle there some routing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parent controller containing some views you can do the following :

```
.controller("parentController", function($scope){

   var self = this;

   $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){    
       self.showButton = (toState.name == "yourStateName");
   });

});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as parentCtrl">
  <ui-view> </ui-view>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button id="search_button" class="button button-icon  ion-ios-search button-clear"  ng-click="search()" ng-if="parentCtrl.showButton">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this worked perfectly fine with a small change. I used a $scope.showButton and also  corrected the toState to toState.name

Comment: Oh right, I forgot it was an object. Edited :) I recommend you to use a `as` syntax; simply ad controller as ctrl. So you can make the difference of which controller property you a refering too

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add a flag to the controller which is responsible for this view and use the ng-if or ng-show/ng-hide directives on the button element. I couldn't give a more detailed answer without more context to the question.

Comment: yes but if i have many views then i must put a flag for each controller. While i consider this as a solution i cannot accept it because im pretty much sure there is a better solution